# java p2p without any framework

Tags: java

I need to develop a p2p application that DOES NOT use any framework like JXTA. I searched through various topics in StackOverflow but I am not getting what I want.  I have a server that maintains the list of clients and its resources. The clients will contact the server to find out which client has what. After the client gets this info from the server, it will establish a p2p connection with the other client - the server is not involved in this.

I need to know as to how to create a client socket and a server socket in the same program i.e the program should like a server and client. Please help me out.

```
for ex:
 client code 
 Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 10000);

 server code
 ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(10000);

     while(true)
     {
        //client socket
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        .......
        .......
     }
```

How will I add a serversocket to my client and make it work like a server? I know I have to use threads, but can anyone explain this in detail? or please post a RELEVANT thread.. I am tired of looking through various forums and websites..

Comment: stackoverflow is for more concrete problems. That's why people is always asking "what have you tried?" "what problem did you get?". In your case what you need is guidance about several topics: how to build a chat/p2p app, how to use plain sockets in Java, and so on. Maybe you can reformulate your question as "recommendation about tutorials on..." listing the concrete things you don't know how to do.

Comment: Sidenote: how to add a "serversocket" and make it work as a server. The only difference is server = passive (listens), client = active (connects). One is listening at some port waiting others (the clients) to connect. Your app must be capable of listening for connections while doing its own stuff (connect to others as a client).

Comment: You will need to have two threads, one for the client and one for the server... (unless you go for NIO based non-blocking IO..  In which case you are better off using a framework as NIO is *hard* to do right). Your code looks fine, just try it!

Comment: @helios: Homework tag is now being phased out.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually many ways to write networking code with respect to threads and IO (see http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html). I guess the traditional way is to create a thread to handle each connection, explained in the bottom of [the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html). This is perfectly fine, if the connection is established, does something, and is then closed.

However, if you keep connections open all the time you may end up creating too many threads and overhead. Hence, the other approaches.

Also, you should consider using some general java networking library. You can implement your own protocol and communication model, but still save some effort and probably end up with better code.

Comment: Also, this is a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215418/java-complete-code-examples-of-thread-per-connection-blocking-io-versus-nio